# Mutually recursive definition of the terms to nonreqursive defenition with Y combinator.

Tags: lambda-calculus

Can't solve this task:

Let there be a mutually recursive definition of the terms ${foo}$ and ${bar}$. In general, it can be written as
$$
{foo}  =  P {foo} {bar}
$$
$$
{bar}  =  Q {foo} {bar}
$$
Here $P$ and $Q$ are some terms that contain neither ${foo}$ nor ${bar}$. Using the $Y$-combinator, find nonrecursive definitions for ${foo}$ and ${bar}$. Try to find the most "compact" solution, with the smallest number of $Y$-combinators possible

#### My attempts

1. I tried to explicitly write $foobar = PfoobarQfoobar$, but it didn't work.
2. I tried to start an auxiliary $bar'=\lambda f.Qf(bar'f)$, and through it get a nonrecursive form with $Y$ combinator.
3. I tried to find the dependence by explicitly describing $foo=Pfoobar=PPfoobarbar=...=P...Pfoobar...bar$.

Comment: Are you interpreting the 1st one as $foo=((P\text{ }foo)(bar))$?

Comment: @SohamSaha Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I have been reading about lambda calculus and combinatory logic only for some months. But I *think* that I have an idea for this question. If you find any problems, *please* comment.**

$$\begin{align*} 
\text{foo} &= \text{P foo bar}\\
&=\text{P foo (Q foo bar)}\\
&=\text{P foo (Q foo (Q foo (...)))}\\
&=\text{P foo (Y (Q foo))}\\
&=\text{P foo (S (K Y) Q foo)}\\
&=\text{S P (S (K Y) Q) foo}\\
&=\text{Y (S P (S (K Y) Q))}
\end{align*}$$

Similarly we can extract a definition for $\text{bar}$

Comment: $\text{P foo (Y (Q foo))}$ why we cant take outside foo at this step?
like: $\text{P foo (Y (Q foo))}=(\lambda f. \text{P f (Y (Q f))) foo}$.

Comment: @replikeit of course we can, but I thought that the situation demanded a purely CL-type solution. If your context permits you to mix combinators with lambda calculus, I don’t think there should be any problem. But I am not experienced enough to know if that is admitted as good practice or not.

Comment: Actually I had done it that way too, but changed it to combinatorial format at the end.

Comment: Then this is right solution. Thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome :) @replikeit

Answer (score 3):

Mutual recursion can always be merged. If $f,g$ are mutually recursive, then define a third function $h = \lambda x. x f g$. Now you can express $f = h (\lambda p q. p)$ (Exercise: express $g$), and write a recursive equation using $h$ alone.

---

Another way to solve this is to solve for $f$ assuming you already know $g$. This gives you an expression $f = \dots g\dots$. Now substitute this into the equation for $g$ and you get a recursive equation for $g$ alone, which you can solve using Y.

Comment: Do you talking something like this: for $foo$ -- $hP = f$ and $f = h(\lambda p q. p)$; for $bar$ -- $hQ = g$ and $g = h(\lambda p q. q)$